# iphone/ipad magazine framework, iScroll or newer?

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, webkit, scroll

i had been using iScroll for a while since the early releases but I'm wondering if there is anything optimized for the classic interactions:

- slide left/right: move (snap to) from story to story
- slide up/down: scroll (natural scroll) the story

I remember some issues due to the locking or nested scrolls...

Is that solved or there is newer plugin that works better?

Answer (score 0):

scrollability - https://github.com/joehewitt/scrollability - from joe hewitt was an improvement over iScroll when it came out. It has support for bidirectional scrolling.

That being said, iScroll 4 is a complete rewrite of iScroll, and just came out a month or two ago. Make sure to give it a try first.